# C, особенности компиляторов Windows

Tags: c, windows, компилятор

Продолжаю перетаскивать код под Windows. С MinGW никаких проблем не возникло, но вот со студией:

1. `open()`/`read()` там находятся в `io.h`. Которого, в свою очередь, нет в mingw :)
2. Сокеты закрываются `closesocket()`, а не `close()`
3. `strncasecmp()` нет
4. `PATH_MAX` нет (но есть `MAX_PATH`)

И т.д.

Всё это вполне безболезненно обходится проверкой `_MSC_VER`.

Есть ещё одна контора, которая Open Watcom юзает. Но тут просто, mingw-код он лопает без изменений.

Какие ещё компиляторы могут встретиться в мире Windows из распространённых, и какие у них могут быть тараканы по сравнению с GNU? Речь пока именно о стандартных библиотеках/макросах.

Comment: Да не морочьте Вы прежде всего себе голову. Делайте все в GNU.

Comment: Студия и ватком - требования. BTW, нашлось ещё (немного не туда, но: http://sourceforge.net/projects/predef/ )

Answer (score 3):

То что Вы перечислили - это не стандартные библиотеки Си, а библиотеки конкретных платформ, и ничего удивительного что они отличаются.

По этому компилятор тут вообще ни при чем, всё дело в библиотеках которые установлены в системе. В комплекте с MinGW обычно идет куча библиотек, обеспечивающих какую-то совместимость с POSIX, а в Visual C++ их естественно нет, так что их надо устанавливать самостоятельно.

---

Насчет `#if defined OS_WIN` - редко когда пишут

```
#if defined OS_WIN
    windows_function(0, y, x, 0);
#else
    posix_function(x, 123, y);
#endif
```

Обычно в обычном коде используют кроссплатформенные обертки типа `function(x, y)`, а весь платформозависимый код выносится в отдельный файл.

Также есть практика размещать код для разных платформ в разных файлах, например `function_win.c`, `function_posix.c` с общим заголовочным файлом `function.h`. Тогда `#if defined` не используется вообще, и выбор конкретной реализации переносится в скрипты системы сборки.

Comment: То есть вы на полном серьёзе предлагаете вместо какого-нибудь `#if defined(_MSC_VER)` в коде - таскать вместе с исходниками все нужные библиотеки под каждую платформу, да ещё и набор стандартных `.h`? Вместе с инструкциями для подмены их в каждом компиляторе? Просто очаровательно :)

Comment: До, такого идиотизма я давно не слышал...

Comment: @klopp: `autoconf`, судя по всему, чем-то подобным и занимается.

Comment: ЕМНИП, autoconf пока ещё не научился менять в исходниках `stricmp` на `strcasecmp`. Только генерить какой-нибудь config.h с расставленными `#ifdef` / `HAVE_*` и генерить нужные Makefile. Но это не решает задачу написания зависимых кусков кода вручную.

Comment: @Abyx, "редко когда пишут" - да просто вечер искромётного юмора сегодня!